# JUnit Testing- Assertion Logic

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am using JUnit 4 for testing this simple code block:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import junit.framework.TestCase;


public class StringUtilsTestSuite extends TestCase {

    public StringUtilsTestSuite(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void testCommaDelimitedListToStringArrayNullProducesEmptyArray(){
        String[] sa = StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToStringArray(null);
        assertTrue("String array isn't null with null input", sa != null);
        assertTrue("String array length == 0 with null input", sa.length == 0);
    }


}
```

The test runs with no errors. My question is why the first assertion passed successfully, I couldn't understand the logic behind the preceding code:

```
String[] sa = StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToStringArray(null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToStringArray() is implemented so that it does not return null, when given a null string, it passes back an empty array.

eg:

```
if (str == null) {
  return new String[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the official StringUtils documentation -

```
Returns:
an array of strings, or the empty array in case of empty input
```

In your example, `sa[]` is now empty, but not null, which is why it passes the first assertion test.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html#commaDelimitedListToStringArray-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 0):

start with reading [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html#commaDelimitedListToStringArray-java.lang.String-) for any methods usage.
If you are interested to see how it has been implemented , i would suggest the [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/springframework/spring/1.2.4/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.java).